# Erro ao tentar Acessar WebService

Tags: web-service, iis

Estou com o seguinte problema,tenho um WebService asmx, postado em um IIS,com a configuração de autenticação setada como Anônima,porem quando tento acessar o mesmo aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Precisso conseguir acessar este WebService para efetuar alguns testes.

Agradeço desde ja.

Comment: Libera o CORS da tua aplicação e desativa a autenticação. Esse problema também pode ser de acesso as pastas no seu servidor.

Comment: Seu webservice é um asmx. wcf ou uma api rest?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo este se trata de um asmx.

Comment: Acessa ele com o caminho completo até o .asmx e adiciona um ?wsdl no final

Comment: Acabei de testar e necessitava o acesso ao caminho completo obrigado pela ajuda de qualquer forma

Comment: Esse endereço é só para esse webservice ou tem um asmx? você pode adicionar esse arquivo como default no IIS.

Comment: Sim esse endereço é exclusivo para este WebService, se eu adicionar como default ele o redireciona ?

Comment: @VictorAugusto Veja a resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por padrão o IIS não possui a extensão .asmx na lista de documentos padrão do website, no seu caso, por não haver nenhum default como última alternativa ele vai tentar exibir a lista de documentos do diretório. Como esse recurso por padrão não é habilitado você recebe a mensagem de erro apresentada em sua pergunta.

Para acessar o seu serviço você deve é necessário utilizar o caminho completo do seu asmx.

Outra alternativa, muito incomum, mas caso esse endereço seja exclusivo para prover esse webservice ou que seja sua principal função.  É adicioná-lo na lista de documentos padrão seguindo os passos ilustrados abaixo.

Porém, é sempre recomendado fornecer o caminho completo do arquivo, pois muitos programas precisam acessar o endpoint com a extensão `.asmx` mais a query `?wsdl` para conseguir realizar o mapeamento dos endpoints e refletir a estrutura de objetos dos seus contratos.

Caso queria deixar esse WS como defult do seu site,  É adicioná-lo na lista de documentos padrão seguindo os passos ilustrados abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso não tenha acesso direto ao Gerenciador do IIS, você pode tentar passar a instrução em seu `Web.config`

```
 <system.webServer>
     <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />               
                <add value="nome_do_seuWS.asmx"/>
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Agora ficou claro a ocorrência do erro Leandro, vou definir o WS como default desse site para testes.Obrigado pelo esclarecimento ,Abs